# Where are the elevation colors in Flutter material you?

Tags: flutter, material-design

I want my TextField widget to be elevated like Card or NavigationBar widgets. I'm using Material 3 (You).[image: How it looks now]

I've tried using surface color from colors like:

```
Theme.of(context).colorScheme.surface
```

but it appears to be the same color as

```
Theme.of(context).colorScheme.background
```

Comment: wrap it with Card widget

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can wrap your text_form_field widget with Card widget and give it elevation as well as boxShadow. It will work for you.

```
Card(
        child: //Your_text_form_field,
      elevation: 10,
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        boxShadow: [
          new BoxShadow(
            color: Colors.red,
            blurRadius: 20.0,
          ),
        ],
      ),
```